# Is new Solaris 10 media licensed to upgrade old Solaris 10 installs?

Tags: oracle, solaris, solaris-10

I've got some Sun hardware that's out of the warranty period.  I'd like to install the latest patches, without the $1000/yr/CPU support contract.  Is the Solaris 10 media kit licensed for upgrades of older Solaris 10 installs that were properly licensed?

Also, the system is used for "production" use, not development and testing.

You can order the media kit from Oracle here:
https://shop.oracle.com/pls/ostore/f?p=ostore:5:7370880112353863:::5:P5_LPI,P5_PROD_HIER_ID:6916731061041191748546,6916016290451192110906

Comment: The only people who can really answer this question are Oracle.

Comment: @Iain: I called Oracle about almost the same issue as the OP, even they couldn't answer it

Comment: That should be covered in the entitlement document that comes with the server.  Of course how many of us actually keep that stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive patches and security fixes you need a support contract.

"Please Note: No commercial license for production use is included as part of this media pack, but can be licensed as part of a Oracle Hardware or Oracle Solaris Premier Subscription for Non-Oracle Hardware purchase."

Comment: I think that's talking about new installs, but better safe than sorry.  We should be OK with Linux ;)